# Why does processing dense geometry consume less power than simple geometry?

Tags: geometry

In [The Road to PS5](https://youtu.be/ph8LyNIT9sg?t=2028), Mark Cerny states:

> It's counter-intuitive, but processing dense geometry typically consumes less power than processing simple geometry.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Is there a way to get context for this question without having to watch a lengthy video?

Comment: @NicolBolas The link should link to the place in the video where the quote is said. You could skip back by a few minutes, but I'm not sure there is much context, other than to make the point that power usage by a GPU is not always intuitive.

Comment: Actually, my question was more what is 'dense' and what is 'simple' in this context?

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah, right. I think he was talking about a few, large triangles compared to many small triangles. His example for simple geometry was a map screen, which would have a few large triangles with textures.